# Delete a File given an url using java

Tags: java

```
        URL urlImage = new URL(candidateImagePath);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(urlImage);
    String imageName = urlImage.getFile().split("/")[3];

    String pathImage = messageSource.getMessage("consultant.image", null,   Locale.ENGLISH)+messageSource.getMessage("system.slash", null, Locale.ENGLISH)+candidateid;
    File fileDir = new File(pathImage); 
    fileDir.mkdirs();
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg" ,new File(pathImage+messageSource.getMessage("system.slash", null, Locale.ENGLISH)+imageName));
```

I am trying to get an image uploaded by iphone guys to a temporary url .
I read the image and write it to my desired location which is 'pathImage'. 
Till here everything works fine.

I want to delete the temporary file in the url.

I want to know how can I delete the image when the url is given in java. Kindly help on this .

Comment: For the questions that you have asked including this one , when you have a good or close enough answer you need you accept it by clicking the Transparent Tick that appears in answers underneath grey up and down arrows.

Comment: Ya .. Thanks .. I read on that jus now .. I ll follow it

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a wrapper on target URL, which will simply delete the file passed as a query string like

```
http://your_temp_url/deleteimage?file=your_temp_file_name
```

in `deleteimage` you will code like this

```
  private void deletefile(String file)
  {
     File f1 = new File(file);
     boolean success = f1.delete();
     if (!success){
     out.println("Deletion failed.");
     }else{
     out.println("File deleted.");
  }
```

This is just one approach to delete the image located on remote machine.

Comment: I don want to write a wrapper on target url. is ther any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

> new File(url.toURI()).delete();

should do the trick.

example:

```
URL url=getClass().getResource("/someresources/resourceFile.txt");
File f=new File(url.toURI());
f.delete();
```